# How to test website on multiple browsers?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I need to test my website on multiple browsers (mainly ie8 & ie7), but bare in mind this website uses PHP which is running on a local server (using WAMP stack). The website is not on-line yet.

Furthermore, the website is interactive so simple screenshots will not do.

Can someone please help me find a tool that helps me test my site keeping in mind of the 2 things mentioned above. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just open your website in those browsers... ?

Comment: [**IETester**](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is great.

Comment: Here’s an idea: open your website in the browsers on your machine. If you’re using a local server, you’ll be able to access your website using a localhost-like URL.

Comment: some browser offer decent emulation tools to view the current site as different versions, browsers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method is to put it **online** and use [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com). It's an online service that creates a virtual machine, forwarded to your computer by Flash. The website will be slow, but still interactive. It's free for 30 minutes, or free for 3 months if you make an account via this [Microsoft website](http://www.modern.ie/fr/virtualization-tools#browserstack). It's then quite cheap for that kind of service.

If you really want to test **on your local server**, you can use Internet Explorer 9, tap the F12 button to bring the developper tools, and then select a browser mode, like IE 7.

[image: Browser Mode; image by Microsoft]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using *WAMP* you can simply launch the desired browser and then go to

> localhost/your_website_folder

Of course you must know where your `localhost` refers to. In [WAMP](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html) it should be

> C:\wamp\www

by default. So to access your website, you need to put it in `C:\wamp\www\your_website_folder`.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.browserstack.com/

This is a web based virtual machine that tests pretty much every browser.

It can also set up a tunnel to test on your local host.

You get a short amount of time for free - just make sure you log out when you finish testing to stop it eating into your free trial period further